# Strange dictionary assignment issue

Tags: python, dictionary

I have 2 models, Albums and Pictures and a function `album_reorder` which receives a list of picture IDs and alters the weights accordingly. This works fine, however I'm trying to write tests for the function, such as:

```
Class ReposTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_album_reorder__fail__not_owned(self):

        # Create a test user, album and pictures.
        user = self.create_test_user()
        # create_default_album() generates an Album along with 6 default Picture records.    
        create_default_album(user)
        album = get_first_album(user.profile)
        pictures = Picture.objects.filter(album=album)

        # Get all picture IDs into a list and record each pictures existing weight.
        picture_ids = []
        picture_weights = {}
        for picture in pictures:
            picture_ids.append(picture.id)
            print "%s:%s:%s" % (album.id, picture.id, picture.weight)
            picture_weights[picture.id] = picture.weight

        # Create another test user, album and pictures.
        user2 = self.create_test_user()
        create_default_album(user2)
        album2 = get_first_album(user2.profile)
        pictures2 = Picture.objects.filter(album=album2)

        # Add a Picture ID from a different user to test the restriction that an album cannot be re-ordered if any pictures do not belong to the specified user.
        picture_ids.append(pictures2[0].id)
        print "%s:%s:%s" % (album2.id, pictures2[0].id, pictures2[0].weight)
        picture_weights[pictures[2].id] = pictures2[0].weight

        # Shuffle all picture IDs
        random = Random()
        while pictures[0].id == picture_ids[0]:
            random.shuffle(picture_ids)

        # Reorder picture IDs according to shuffled ID list, however this should fail due to the ownership check.
        album_reorder(user, picture_ids)
        print picture_ids
        print picture_weights

        # Check each
        for picture_id in picture_ids:
            self.assertEqual(picture_weights[picture_id], Picture.objects.get(id=picture_id).weight)
```

Now the problem seems to be in the way the `picture_weights` dict is constructed. Since the following two lines output:

```
# Loop output: (album.id, picture.id, picture.weight)
# 1346:5699:0
# 1346:5700:1
# 1346:5701:2
# 1346:5702:3
# 1346:5703:4
# 1346:5704:5
# 1347:5705:0

print picture_ids
# Outputs: [5700L, 5703L, 5702L, 5699L, 5704L, 5705L, 5701L]

print picture_weights
# Outputs: {5699L: 0L, 5700L: 1L, 5701L: 0L, 5702L: 3L, 5703L: 4L, 5704L: 5L}
```

Note that `picture_ids` is 7 elements long, as expected, where as `picture_weights` is only  6 elements, and the weights do not match those as output from the loop. The second user picture `5705` is missing from `picture_weights` however one of the `picture_weights` has been assigned the incorrect weight of `0L`.

I'm not experienced with dict's at all however, I'm just trying to apply my knowledge of PHP Associative arrays so I'm assuming I have a gap in my knowledge there. Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Why do you have the line `picture_weights[pictures[2].id] = pictures2[0].weight` instead of `picture_weights[pictures2[0].id] = pictures2[0].weight`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list and dictionary diverge at these lines:

```
    # Add a Picture ID from a different user to test the restriction that an album cannot be re-ordered if any pictures do not belong to the specified user.
    picture_ids.append(pictures2[0].id)
    print "%s:%s:%s" % (album2.id, pictures2[0].id, pictures2[0].weight)
    picture_weights[pictures[2].id] = pictures2[0].weight
```

Notice how you used `pictures[2].id`, which is `5701L` (and that's why that specific key's weight changes in the dictionary). You probably meant for the line to be:

```
    picture_weights[pictures2[0].id] = pictures2[0].weight
```

Comment: Fixed! Sorry about that *blush*

Comment: No worries, it happens to all of us.